# Dynamic parameters in Powershell based on value of other parameter

Tags: powershell, powershell-core

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=0)]
    [string]
    $subscription,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [string]
    $applicationId,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [string]
    $clientSecret,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=1)]
    [string]
    $resourceGroupName,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=2)]
    [string]
    $apimServiceName,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=3)]
    [string]
    $policyfilePath,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=4)]
    [ValidateSet('global','product','api','operation', IgnoreCase = $true)]
    [string]
    $scope='global',
    
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=5)]
    [string]
    $apiIdOrProductId

    #THIS IS THE PARAMETER WHICH I WANT TO MAKE MANDATORY IF VALUE OF PREVIOUS PARAMETER $scope = "OPEARTION"
    #[Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    #[string]
    #$operationname
)

DynamicParam {
    if ($scope -eq "OPERATION" -or $scope -eq "operation") {
         #create a new ParameterAttribute Object
         Write-Host "Called test"
         Write-Host $scope
         $operationAttribute = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute
         $operationAttribute.Mandatory = $true
         $operationAttribute.Position = 6
         
         #create an attributecollection object for the attribute we just created.
         $attributeCollection = new-object System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[System.Attribute]

         #add our custom attribute
         $attributeCollection.Add($operationAttribute)

         #add our paramater specifying the attribute collection
         $operationName = New-Object System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter('operationname', [String], $attributeCollection)

         #expose the name of our parameter
         $paramDictionary = New-Object System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameterDictionary
         $paramDictionary.Add('operationname', $operationName)
         return $paramDictionary
   }

}
```

I cannot get the dynamic parameter to work which is dependent on a previous parameter "scope". It just skips over when I run the PS script. Please advice what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: As an aside: PowerShell's operators are case-_insensitive_ by default, so `-eq 'operation` will do; in case you do need case-sensitivity, there are `c`-prefixed variants (`-ceq 'operation'`)

Comment: Works fine for me too in 5.1 ... `. "C:\Github\test.ps1" -scope operation ` show me operationname in the arguments and all other scope do not. (tested within vscode)

Comment: I was running the script without arguments so was allowing the command line to prompt me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your code only works if you pass an argument to your `-scope` parameter *directly on the command line*.
- If you let PowerShell *prompt* you for a `-scope` argument, based on the parameter's `Mandatory` property, your code cannot work, because the `dynamicparam` block runs *before* such automatic prompts.

Since you're assigning a *default value* to `$scope`, `'global'` (which doesn't make sense in combination with `Mandatory=$true`), one option is to simply remove the `Mandatory` property:

- This will default to `'global'` in the absence of a (possibly positional) `-scope` argument, in which case you know that the additional parameter isn't required.
- If an argument *is* specified, then your `dynamicparam` block will work as intended.

However, this also requires you to place the mandatory `$apiIdOrProductId` parameter declaration *before* `$scope` (swap `Position` values `4` and `5`)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the title, there is at least one way to have a dynamic param offer a ValidateSet for that dynamic parameter based on the value of a previously entered regular parameter.

In this case the regular parameter could be a folder.
But you would have to enter it without quotes.

For instance:

```
Function Get-SubFolderDynamically {
[CmdletBinding()]
param($path)
    
dynamicparam
{
    Write-Verbose "DynamicParam triggered. PSBoundParameters `$path is currently: $($PSBoundParameters['path'])" -Verbose
    
        #Parameter Definition
            $attributes = New-Object -Type System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute
            $attributes.Mandatory = $true
            $attributeCollection = New-Object -Type System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[System.Attribute]
            $attributeCollection.Add($attributes)

        #AcceptedValues for Parameter Definition
        #Note: Only Works if path is entered in the command line without quotes
            $subFolders = (Get-ChildItem $path).Name
            $attributeCollection.add((New-Object System.Management.Automation.ValidateSetAttribute($subFolders)))

        #ParameterDictionary
            $dynParam = New-Object -Type System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter("subFolder", [string], $attributeCollection)
            $paramDictionary = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameterDictionary
            $paramDictionary.Add("subFolder", $dynParam)
        
        return $paramDictionary
}

}
```

#RUNIT - Create a Folder with subFolders to test.

```
Get-SubFolderDynamically -path C:\PathWithoutQuotes -subFolder [TAB|TAB|...]
```