# Have parameterSet based on a parameter value

Tags: powershell, parameters, parameter-sets

I've the following sample function

```
function Update-ExceptionPolicy {
        [CmdletBinding()]
        param(
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'WindowsFolderException')]
        $folder,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'WindowsFileException')]
        $file,

        $path,

        [ValidateSet(
            'WindowsFolderException',
            'WindowsFileException'
        )]
        [string]
        $ExceptionType
    )
}
```

due to some external constraints, I'm trying to see if it's possible to design the function and ParameterSets based on the value of `$ExceptionType` via a ValidateSet list.

For example when trying to autocomplete the 2nd parameter I should either get "-file" or "-folder" based on the previous parameter value :

```
Update-ExceptionPolicy -ExceptionType WindowsFileException -<tab to autocomplete should show "-file">

Update-ExceptionPolicy -ExceptionType WindowsFolderException -<tab to autocomplete should show "-folder">
```

I've tried to have a look at dynamic parameters ([this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24243199/2552996) looked like an elegant solution even) but in my opinion it looks like a complex solution for a simple problem.

PS: I know I could also just split `$ExceptionType` into 2 switches but I don't want to do that because my project involves dozen of potentially complex parameter sets. Get it from the value could really be the best design here

Comment: split `$ExceptionType` into 2 parameters, `-WindowsFolderException` and `-WindowsFileException` then there is no problem with parameter sets. Much better option than using dynamic parameters.

Comment: I agree, but as I mentioned, I have plenty of different kinds of exceptions to handle. I wanted some kind of centralized/guided way instead of having dozen of different exception switches

Comment: you will need dynamic params then. not something I would recommend. would much rather have 2 functions than that.

Comment: @Douda here is a similar case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65221816/dynamic-parameters-in-powershell-based-on-value-of-other-parameter

Comment: Why do you need to combine two parameters to pick a parameter set? Why not just remove the `$file` and `$folder` parameters all together and then decide based on the `-ExceptionType` argument alone?

Comment: For the sake of example, I just showed a sample of the work. I've many different parameters (IPs/ranges/domain names/extensions etc..) each of them have a subset of exceptions and so on. I still need other parameters to define the exceptions on top of the "exception type" I'm trying to centralize. Some parameter sets have common parameters (if that makes sense)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen just a quick one while I'm at it. You mentioned why not just decide based on -ExceptionType argument. I want to decide based on the value of this parameter only, but apparently I can't without using dynamic parameters from my understanding

Comment: @Douda If you have multiple tasks to perform, all with different parameter surfaces, then you'll probably want to write _multiple_ functions instead. Trying to pack all your functionality into a [god command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object) is kind of antithetical to PowerShell's design philosophy (roughly summarized as "each command should do 1 thing well and be easy to use in composition with other commands if applicable").